# How can I use iteration to find value that will balance equation in MS Excel 2016

Tags: excel, iteration

I've got a spreadsheet with a complex series of formulas based on a value x. Currently, the user has to enter a guess at x and adjust it until the difference between the result of all the calculations (using x) equals a pre-set value y.  The way the spreadsheet is set up now, x and y are in two cells and a third cell shows the difference between them (let's call it z). So the user just adjusts their guess at x up and down until the z is as close to zero as possible.

Is there any way I can automate that last step, so Excel will just iterate through possible values of x until z = 0?

Comment: Have you tried Goal Seek?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel has a "Solver" feature, which you can use for finding a value, based on the result of formulae. It's an add-in, you need to activate it.

Hereby a screenshot of what it looks like: B1 = A1^2, I would like to know the square root of 5:

[image]

More information can be found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-and-solve-a-problem-by-using-solver-5d1a388f-079d-43ac-a7eb-f63e45925040).

Comment: A better reference is Practical Management Science by Winston & Albright.

Comment: @SolarMike: do you have an URL for this?

Comment: it’s old tech - a book, but I think it may be online as a pdf… But as I have 3 or 4 copies as versions changed I have not checked. However, it has some very good and classic models in it.